# prepared statement - using parameter to specify table name

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

using pgadmin4, postgres 9.6 on windows 10

I'm trying to use parameter to specify table name in a prepared statement as in the code below. However I do get a syntax error as below. Note that I'm able to use the parameters with a `where` condition et al.

**Query**

```
prepare mySelect(text) as 
    select * 
        from $1
        limit 100;

execute mySelect('some_table');
```

**pgAdmin message**

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 3:      from $1
                  ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 50
```

Comment: As @Pavel said it is not possible but u can create function for that situation and use EXECUTE

Comment: can you add an example for the above context ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible. The prepare statement is persistent execution plan - and execution plan contains pined source of data - so tables, column names cannot be mutable there.

When you change table, columns, then you change the semantic of query - you will got different execution plan and then this behave is not possible in prepared statements. The main use case of prepared statements is reusing of execution plans - plan once, execute more. But there are some principal limits - only some parameters can be changed.

Comment: What is the alternative to this - for better reuse of a certain query across different tables. Also to further extend it across diff column names ?

Comment: @user3206440 - there is not a alternative, sorry. The planning time is usually very low - less than 1ms - so it is not problem. Every time - depends on context. If you have well designed database schema, then sharing query has not any sense.